# Problema con las clases internas en java

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Siempre he tenido un problema a trabajar en varios proyectos en Android Studio. Uno de ellos es el acceso a las variables que se instancian dentro de una funcion de una clase externa. Ejempo:

public void listaHoteles  (Bundle savedInstanceState){

```
    //initilizing firestorage
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mapa");

    storageRef = storage.getReference();


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Double lat = (Double) snapshot.child("lat").getValue();
                Double lon = (Double) snapshot.child("lon").getValue();

                if(lat != null && lon!= null) {

                    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(snapshot.getKey(), Point.fromLngLat(lon,lat));
                    mapaSitiosViewModel.addHotel(hotel);

                    /*

                    // [START download_create_reference]
                    String reference = "mapa/"+titulo+".PNG";
                    // Create a storage reference from our app

                    // [START download_to_memory]
                    StorageReference hotelRef = storageRef.child(reference);
                    // [START download_via_url]
                    hotelRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'

                            Hotel hotel = new Hotel(uri, titulo, ubicacion);
                            mapaSitiosViewModel.addHotel(hotel);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            Timber.d("Una de los Hoteles no presenta imagen");
                            //Mandar notificacion a la central
                        }
                    });
                    // [END download_via_url]

                     */
                }else {
                    //Mandar notificacion a la central
                    Timber.d("Una de los Hoteles esta registrado pero no presenta localizacion");
                }
            }

            // Initialize the map view

            mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.mapView2);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            initRecyclerView(root);
            mapView.getMapAsync(MapaSitiosFragment.this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Timber.e(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Esta en una funcion dentro de mi activity Hotel, queria guardar todos los datos de mi database en una lista pero cuando otra funcion quiere recorrer dicha lista, esta sale vacia, null. Hay algun metodo para que no me pase esto o estoy haciendo ago mal_?.

Comment: Cual vendria a ser el problema que sale vacia ? podrias detallar esa parte? gracias

Comment: sip o que hago en si es llenar una lista con objetos Hotel de mi base de datos en firebase en el metodo onDataChange(), pero si yo quiero recorrer la lista despues fuera del metodo me sale vacia si lo hago dentro del onDataChange si me salen los datos.

Comment: hola! Puedes Intentar crear una lista a nivel de la clase  y luego cada vez que se llama al método  onDataChange() rellenas esa lista.